# Error while build comman react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I am facing some errors while running the command react-native run-ios .
Everything is fine and there are no errors in the code or libraries.
I am facing issues while building the project files.

Below is the screenshot for the same:

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "0.63.4",

[image]

My simulator gets opened but the application is not getting installed.